# Powershell 5 custom class

Tags: class, powershell

I'm creating a simple custom class in Powershell 5 that converts an alphanumeric string into an integer.

Usage:

```
$test = [newclass]::new("B8")
$test.Value         // 118 # type int
$test.ToString()    // B8  # type string
```

Is there a way to return the 118 (currently using the `Value` property) by referencing just the `$test` variable?

Essentially I would like for `$test` to return `118` without having to use the `Value` property.

```
Class newclass {

    # Hidden properties
    hidden [string]$AlphaNumericValue

    # Properties
    [int]$Value

    # Methods
    [string]ToString() {
        Return $this.AlphaNumericValue
        }

    # Constructors
    newclass([string]$String) {
        $this.AlphaNumericValue = $String
        $this.Value = If ($String -match "^0[0-9]$") {
            $String.Substring(1)
            }

        ElseIf ($String -match "^[1-9][0-9]$") {
            $String
            } 

        ElseIf ($String -match "^[a-zA-Z][0-9]$") {
            Switch ($String.Substring(0,1)) {
                "A" {"10$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "B" {"11$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "C" {"12$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "D" {"13$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "E" {"14$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "F" {"15$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "G" {"16$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "H" {"17$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "I" {"18$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "J" {"19$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "K" {"20$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "L" {"21$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "M" {"22$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "N" {"23$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "O" {"24$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "P" {"25$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "Q" {"26$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "R" {"27$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "S" {"28$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "T" {"29$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "U" {"30$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "V" {"31$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "W" {"32$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "X" {"33$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "Y" {"34$($String.Substring(1))"}
                "Z" {"35$($String.Substring(1))"}         
                }
            }
        Else {
            throw "Invalid format"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first two cases are the same, cast it to an integer and the leading 0 disappears because integers have no leading zeros. `[int]('{0}{1}' -f ([int]$String.ToUpper()[0] - 55), $String[1])` will do the long conversion in one line by taking the uppercase character value (A=65)  and -55 from it so A starts at 10, and casting the result to int.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - nice comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method that will do that:

```
static [int] justValue ([string]$input) 
{

    return ([newclass]::new($input)).Value

}
```

insert that before your last }

```
C:\> [newclass]::justValue("B8")
118
C:\>
```